# Web8 upgrade issue configuring Session Preview webservice

Tags: experience-manager, odata, upgrade, session-preview, web8

I am upgrading a dev environment from 2013SP1 to Web8 keeping it simple for now using legacy in-process APIs.
I have a dedicated new CD webservice Java webapp created from the provided .war file.

The odata.svc is reachable just fine when I disable oAuth, and lists the available entities. However hitting Refresh Preview in XPM fails with the following in the Windows event log:

> Unable to update the changes using OData Service.
>   An error occurred while processing this request.
>   The expected content type for a batch requests is "multipart/mixed;boundary=batch" not "application/xml".
>     Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PreviewService Errorcode: 1003 User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE  StackTrace Information Details:
>      at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveResult.HandleBatchResponse()
>      at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveResult.HandleBatchResponse()
>      at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveResult.EndRequest()
>      at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions options)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PreviewService.ServiceImplementation.Preview(IEnumerable`1 publishedItemsInfo, TcmUri publishingTargetId)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PreviewService.ServiceImplementation.Preview(IEnumerable`1 publishedItemsInfo, TcmUri publishingTargetId)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PreviewService.FastTrackPublishingService.Preview(IEnumerable`1 publishedItemsInfo, TcmUri publishingTargetId)
>      at SyncInvokePreview(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)

And the following in the cd_core log:

> 2016-01-25 17:46:23,560 DEBUG ServerEngine - Running request start claim processor class com.sdl.web.content.claimprocessor.WritableODataClaimProcessor
>   2016-01-25 17:46:23,566 DEBUG ODataServiceImpl - Handling request: POST http://mydemo.com:8080/cd_webservice/odata.svc/$batch
>   2016-01-25 17:46:23,572 DEBUG ODataParserImpl - Parsing URI: http://mydemo.com:8080/cd_webservice/odata.svc/$batch
>   2016-01-25 17:46:23,573 DEBUG ODataParserImpl - Parse result: ODataUri(http://mydemo.com:8080/cd_webservice/odata.svc,BatchUri)
>   2016-01-25 17:46:23,648 DEBUG AtomUnmarshaller - Match for AtomUnmarshaller: POST http://mydemo.com:8080/cd_webservice/odata.svc/$batch with score: 0
>   2016-01-25 17:46:23,650 DEBUG BatchUnmarshaller - Matched MultipartUnmarshaller: POST http://mydemo.com:8080/cd_webservice/odata.svc/$batch with score: 180
>   2016-01-25 17:46:23,650 DEBUG JsonUnmarshaller - Match for JsonUnmarshaller: POST http://mydemo.com:8080/cd_webservice/odata.svc/$batch with score: 0
>   2016-01-25 17:46:23,655 INFO  BatchUnmarshaller - Multipart unmarshaller invoked with POST http://mydemo.com:8080/cd_webservice/odata.svc/$batch
>   2016-01-25 17:46:23,782 DEBUG ODataMessageRouter - Sending error message for exception:
>   com.sdl.odata.api.parser.ODataBatchParseException: `DELETE ' expected but`M' found
>       at com.sdl.odata.parser.ODataBatchRequestParser.parseBatch(ODataBatchRequestParser.scala:49) ~[odata_parser-2.0.0-1218.jar:2.0.0-1218]
>       at com.sdl.odata.unmarshaller.batch.ODataBatchParser.processEntity(ODataBatchParser.java:44) ~[odata_renderer-2.0.0-1218.jar:2.0.0-1218]
>       at com.sdl.odata.unmarshaller.AbstractParser.getODataEntity(AbstractParser.java:79) ~[odata_renderer-2.0.0-1218.jar:2.0.0-1218]
>       at com.sdl.odata.unmarshaller.batch.BatchUnmarshaller.unmarshall(BatchUnmarshaller.java:60) ~[odata_renderer-2.0.0-1218.jar:2.0.0-1218]
>       at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataUnmarshallerActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ODataUnmarshallerActor.scala:37) ~[odata_service-2.0.0-1218.jar:2.0.0-1218]
>       at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465) ~[akka-actor_2.10-2.3.2.jar:na]
>       at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataUnmarshallerActor.aroundReceive(ODataUnmarshallerActor.scala:30) ~[odata_service-2.0.0-1218.jar:2.0.0-1218]
>       at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516) ~[akka-actor_2.10-2.3.2.jar:na]
>       at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487) ~[akka-actor_2.10-2.3.2.jar:na]
>       at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238) ~[akka-actor_2.10-2.3.2.jar:na]
>       at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220) ~[akka-actor_2.10-2.3.2.jar:na]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
>   2016-01-25 17:46:23,786 DEBUG JsonServiceDocumentRenderer - Score of JSON service document renderer is 0
>   2016-01-25 17:46:23,786 DEBUG XMLServiceDocumentRenderer - Score of XML service document renderer is 0
>   2016-01-25 17:46:23,787 DEBUG XMLErrorResponseRenderer - Start rendering error response for request: POST http://mydemo.com:8080/cd_webservice/odata.svc/$batch
>   2016-01-25 17:46:23,788 DEBUG XMLErrorResponseRenderer - End rendering error response for request: POST http://mydemo.com:8080/cd_webservice/odata.svc/$batch
>   2016-01-25 17:46:23,789 DEBUG ODataServiceImpl - Request completed in 223

- I am using the cd_ambient_conf.xml as provided in the .war file
- Do I need to change something in the web.xml to set the requests content type?
- I tried to disable the ReadWrite filter in web.xml but it does not change the result

Any pointers are welcome! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I find this very strange, it almost looks like you are trying to send preview content to a non preview enabled webservice. The error you are getting on the Webservice side indicates that it is using the new OData v4 Batching endpoint which is not meant for preview actions.

Are you sure you installed 'preview/service/standalone/' or its equivelant war file for the preview webservice? Keep in mind that you cannot use the content-service for this, you need to have this seperate preview webservice for sending the preview batch content.

This means in your discovery service your preview capability needs to point to this preview webservice. Have you done this?

Comment: Thanks Renze, I will try the micro service instead. I did not use the discovery service as in legacy mode I thought I could keep the publication target config to point to the preview webservice endpoint

Comment: It is my understanding that CD always needs the discovery service, even if you're not using Topology Manager

Comment: ok good to know I will register it there then. thanks

Comment: Apart from Configuring the location of the Discovery Service in the web.config of my staging site, do I need to configure it somewhere else like in the cd_storage_conf.xml?

Comment: Hi Philippe, could you resolved this issue? I have installed with Legacy mode to, but i'm not sure if I need to install and configure DiscoveryService. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually I needed to upgrade my environment with latest OS and Sql Server so I decided to start fresh and just reuse the content. So I do not use the legacy mode anymore but microservices instead. Also I recommend to install Web8.1.1 which has lots of fixes in it. As Nuno mentioned above it seems that you need the discovery service installed even in legacy mode.